# Transient annotation in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have used Transient annotation in hibernate to stop that property from insertion  but i want that column to be selected on select query. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: if you have not inserted the property how can you select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to mark a read-only property, you will have to define it as follows:

```
@Column(name = "columnname", insertable= false, updatable= false)
```

Comment: @KrisnelaTPL That's fine. If it helped you, you might just accept it (the check mark on the left side).